# Inheriting superclass properties in subclasses

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

For help you help me i'm going to illustrate the problem with an example:

```
var SuperClass = function() {
  this.propertieOfSuperClass = 'A';

  this.init();
};

SuperClass.prototype.init = function() {
 console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // ouput 'A';
};
```

```
// Some code here to do the magic for SubClass1
// Some code here to do the magic for SubClass2
```

SubClass1:

```
var SubClass1 = function() {
  this.methodOfSubClass1();
};

SubClass1.prototype.methodOfSubClass1 = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};
```

SubClass2:

```
var SubClass2 = function() {
  this.methodOfSubClass2();
};

SubClass2.prototype.methodOfSubClass = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};
```

I want be able to have this SuperClass which i set the properties and other two subclasses which i can access the properties of SuperClass, but without lose the scope.

I was trying to use inside of my SuperClass init method:

```
SubClass1.call(this);
SubClass2.call(this);
```

And this will make the properties of `SuperClass` accessible, but the SubClass's will lost their scope, so i cant call `methodOfSubClass1` and `methodOfSubClass2`, because they doesn't exist in the `SuperClass`.

This could be solved?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 kind of inheritance possible in JavaScript.

1)  Pseudo Classical :

```
/**
 * Create a new constructor function, whose prototype is the parent   object's prototype.
 * Set the child's prototype to the newly created constructor function.
 **/

var extendObj = function (childObj, parentObj) {
    var tmpObj = function () {}
    tmpObj.prototype = parentObj.prototype;
    childObj.prototype = new tmpObj();
    childObj.prototype.constructor = childObj;
};
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/4wzuwhqw/)

2) Functional (https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/eh7u4pxd/)

3) Prototypal (Object.create) (https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/dnjkx8w1/)

Comment: this won't change anything, i need to be able to create methods in the childObj, i just can access properties and methods from the parentObj.......

Comment: that's because you are not following the correct way. Check https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/vm6bn2bh/

Comment: Hm, this is not exactly what i'm searching for, i want be able to inherit properties from the parent object in the child object and don't lose the scope of the child.. this is not possible?

Comment: You should read the correct way of implementing inheritance first.

Comment: its possible with functional inheritance. Read in my post about that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem . For more inheritance doubts  follow eric elliot [Prototype Inheritance  vs classical inheritance](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a)

```js
var SuperClass =  {
  propertieOfSuperClass : 'A',
  init : function init() {
     return this.propertieOfSuperClass;
  }
 };




var SubClass1 = Object.create(SuperClass);





SubClass1.methodOfSubClass1 = function() {
  return this.propertieOfSuperClass;
};

console.log(SubClass1.methodOfSubClass1());
```